# Function Not Being Executed - JS Budget App

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a budget tracker app for learning purposes, and while trying to update some labels in the DOM, I've noticed that the function nodeListForEach isn't being executed.

I've inserted some console logged strings to roughly "debug" my code and I always get the "Crossed line 289" one, but not the "Test" one (which is inside the function that I need to be executed). Sorry for the huge amount of code, but I can't understand what is causing the error and where.

```
// BUDGET
var budgetController = (function () {

    var Expense = function (id, description, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
        this.percentage = -1;
    };

    Expense.prototype.calcPercentage = function (totalIncome) {
        if (totalIncome > 0) {
            this.percentage = Math.round((this.value / totalIncome) * 100);
        } else {
            this.percentage = -1;
        }
    };

    Expense.prototype.getPercentage = function () {
        return this.percentage;
    }

    var Income = function (id, description, value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var calculateTotal = function (type) {
        var sum = 0;

        data.allItems[type].forEach(function (cur) {
            sum += cur.value;
        });

        data.totals[type] = sum;
    };


    var data = {
        allItems: {
            exp: [],
            inc: []
        },
        totals: {
            exp: 0,
            inc: 0
        },
        budget: 0,
        percentage: -1
    };

    return {
        addItem: function (type, des, val) {
            var newItem, id;

            function newID(lenght) {
                var result = '';
                var prefix = '';
                var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789';
                var charactersLength = characters.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
                    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
                }

                if (type === "inc") {
                    prefix = "I-"
                } else {
                    prefix = "E-"
                }

                return prefix + result;
            }

            // Generating a New Unique ID
            id = newID(5);


            // Checking for Type
            if (type === "exp") {
                newItem = new Expense(id, des, val);
            } else if (type === "inc") {
                newItem = new Income(id, des, val);
            }

            // Pushing Into Data Structure
            data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

            // Returning New Element
            return newItem;
        },

        deleteItem: function (type, id) {
            var ids, index, newType;

            // id = 6
            // ids = [1, 2, 3, 7, 6]
            // index = 4

            var ids = data.allItems[type].map(function (current) {
                return current.id;
            });

            if (type === "inc") {
                newType = "I-";
            } else if (type === "exp") {
                newType = "E-";
            } else {
                console.log("Type Conversion Error");
            }

            index = ids.indexOf(newType + id);


            console.log(index);

            if (index !== -1) {
                data.allItems[type].splice(index, 1);
                console.log("Item Successfully Deleted");
            } else {
                console.log("Errror Occured");
            }


        },

        calculateBudget: function () {

            // A > Calculate Total Income & Expenses
            calculateTotal("exp");
            calculateTotal("inc");

            // B > Calculate Budget = income - expenses
            data.budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;

            if (data.totals.inc > 0) {
                // C > Calculate Percentage of Income we Spent
                data.percentage = Math.round((data.totals.exp * 100) / data.totals.inc);
            } else {
                data.percentage = -1;
            }



        },

        calculatePercentages: function () {

            data.allItems.exp.forEach(function (cur) {
                cur.calcPercentage(data.totals.inc);
            });

        },

        getPercentages: function () {
            var allPercentages = data.allItems.exp.map(function (cur) {
                console.log(cur.getPercentage());
                return cur.getPercentage();

            });

            return allPercentages;
        },

        getBudget: function () {
            return {
                budget: data.budget,
                totalIncome: data.totals.inc,
                totalExpenses: data.totals.exp,
                percentage: data.percentage
            }
        },

        testing: function () {
            console.log(data);
        }


    }

})();

// USER INTERFACE
var UIController = (function () {

    var DOMstrings = {
        inputType: ".add__type",
        inputDesc: ".add__description",
        inputValue: ".add__value",
        inputBtn: ".add__btn",
        incomeContainer: ".income__list",
        expensesContainer: ".expenses__list",
        container: ".container",
        expensesPercLabel: ".item__percentage"
    }




    return {
        getInput: function () {
            return {
                type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value, // inc or exp
                description: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDesc).value,
                value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputValue).value)
            };
        },


        addListItem: function (obj, type) {
            var html, newHtml, element;
            // Create HTML string with placeholder text

            if (type === 'inc') {
                element = DOMstrings.incomeContainer;

                html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="%id%"> <div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="item__id"> %id% </div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">+ €%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
            } else if (type === 'exp') {
                element = DOMstrings.expensesContainer;

                html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="item__id"> %id% </div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">- €%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
            }

            // Replace the placeholder text with some actual data
            newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%id%', obj.id);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
            newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value.toFixed(2));

            // Insert the HTML into the DOM
            document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
        },

        deleteListItem: function (selectorID) {
            var el = document.getElementById(selectorID);
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        },

        clearFields: function () {
            var fields;

            fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.inputDesc + ", " + DOMstrings.inputValue);

            var fieldsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);

            fieldsArray.forEach(function (current, index, array) {
                current.value = "";
            });

            fieldsArray[0].focus();
        },

        displayBudget: function (data) {
            if (data.budget > 0) {
                document.querySelector(".budget__value").textContent = "+ €" + data.budget.toFixed(2);
            } else if (data.budget < 0) {
                document.querySelector(".budget__value").textContent = "- €" + data.budget.toFixed(2);
            } else {
                document.querySelector(".budget__value").textContent = "€" + data.budget.toFixed(2);
            }

            document.querySelector(".budget__income--value").textContent = "+ €" + data.totalIncome.toFixed(2);
            document.querySelector(".budget__expenses--value").textContent = "- €" + data.totalExpenses.toFixed(2);

            if (data.percentage <= 0) {
                document.getElementById("in%").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                document.getElementById("in%").classList.add("budget__income--percentage");
                document.getElementById("in%").classList.remove("budget__expenses--percentage");
            } else {
                document.getElementById("in%").classList.add("budget__expenses--percentage");
                document.querySelector(".budget__expenses--percentage").textContent = data.percentage + "%";
            }
        },

        displayPercentages: function (percentages) {

            var fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMstrings.expensesPercLabel);

            var nodeListForEach = function (list, callback) {

                for (var i = 0; i < list.lenght; i++) {
                    callback(list[i], i);
                }

            };


            console.log("Crossed line 289...");
            nodeListForEach(fields, function (current, index) {

                console.log("Test");
                current.textContent = percentages[index] + "%";

            });

        },

        getDOMstrings: function () {
            return DOMstrings
        },

        displayMonth: function () {
            var d = new Date();
            var month = new Array();
            month[0] = "January";
            month[1] = "February";
            month[2] = "March";
            month[3] = "April";
            month[4] = "May";
            month[5] = "June";
            month[6] = "July";
            month[7] = "August";
            month[8] = "September";
            month[9] = "October";
            month[10] = "November";
            month[11] = "December";
            var n = month[d.getMonth()];
            document.querySelector(".budget__title--month").textContent = n;
        }


    }

})();

// CONTROLLER
var appController = (function (budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

    // Setting Up All Event Listeners
    var setupEventListeners = function () {

        var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

        document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);

        document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {

            // Checking for the enter key pressed
            if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.wich === 13) {
                ctrlAddItem();
            }
        });

        document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener("click", ctrlDeleteItem);

    };

    var updatePercentages = function () {
        var percentages;

        // A > Calculate Percentages
        budgetCtrl.calculatePercentages();

        // B > Read Percentages from Budet Controller
        percentages = budgetCtrl.getPercentages();

        console.log("Got Here...");
        // C > Update the UI with new Percentages
        UICtrl.displayPercentages(percentages);
    };

    var updateBudget = function () {
        // D > Calculate Budget
        budgetController.calculateBudget();

        // D.1 > Return Budget
        var data = budgetController.getBudget();

        // E > Display Budget in UI
        UICtrl.displayBudget(data);

    };


    var ctrlAddItem = function () {
        var input, newItem;

        // A > Get the input field data
        input = UIController.getInput();

        if (input.description !== "" && !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0) {
            // B > Add the item to budget controller module
            newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);

            // C > Add item to UI
            UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);
            console.log(newItem);

            // C.1 > Clear All Fields
            UICtrl.clearFields();

            // Recalling Budget Functions...
            updateBudget();

            // Calculate and Update Percentages
            updatePercentages();
        }
    };

    var ctrlDeleteItem = function (event) {
        var itemID, splitID, type, ID;

        itemID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;

        if (itemID) {

            // Splitting differents parts of ID
            splitID = itemID.split("-");
            console.log("SplitID > " + splitID);
            type = splitID[0];
            ID = splitID[1];

            if (type === "I") {
                type = "inc";
            } else if (type === "E") {
                type = "exp";
            }

            // A > Delete Item from Data Sructure
            budgetCtrl.deleteItem(type, ID);

            // B > Delete Item from UI
            UICtrl.deleteListItem(itemID);

            // C > Update and Show the new Budget
            updateBudget();
        }
    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            console.log("Application has started...");
            setupEventListeners();
            UICtrl.displayBudget({
                budget: 0,
                totalIncome: 0,
                totalExpenses: 0,
                percentage: 0
            });
            UICtrl.displayMonth();
        }
    }

})(budgetController, UIController);

// INIT FUNCTION RECALL > STARTING THE APPLICATION
appController.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One: If you're not planning on changing your function nodelistfor each, I would use const instead of variable. Your code will be cleaner that way.
Two: It looks like your problem Is in line 281, inside the for block definition, it looks like you mispelled length